# Couldn't match type error when implementing type class function

Tags: haskell, graph, instance, typeclass, type-signature

I am trying to build my own simple graph library that I can use for advent of code. I have a type class `Graph` and one concrete implementation `MapGraph` that uses `Data.Map`

```
class Graph g where
  nodeSet :: (Ord n) => g -> S.Set n
```

```
data MapGraph e n = MapGraph {mGraph :: M.Map n [(e,n)]} deriving Show

instance (Ord e,Ord n) => Graph (MapGraph e n) where
  nodeSet mapGraph = S.fromList $ M.keys $ mGraph mapGraph
```

The `nodeSet` function works correctly if I have it as a standalone function outside of the instance declaration

```
testNodeSet mapGraph = S.fromList $ M.keys $ mGraph mapGraph

*Main> testNodeSet $ mapGraphFromEdgeList $ parseEdgeList connectionList
fromList ["B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","S"]
```

But I get a compile error from it inside of the instance

```
Main.hs:59:22: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘n1’ with ‘n’
      ‘n1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          nodeSet :: forall n1. Ord n1 => MapGraph e n -> S.Set n1
        at Main.hs:59:3-9
      ‘n’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the instance declaration
        at Main.hs:58:10-46
      Expected type: S.Set n1
        Actual type: S.Set n
    • In the expression: S.fromList $ M.keys $ mGraph mapGraph
      In an equation for ‘nodeSet’:
          nodeSet mapGraph = S.fromList $ M.keys $ mGraph mapGraph
      In the instance declaration for ‘Graph (MapGraph e n)’
    • Relevant bindings include
        mapGraph :: MapGraph e n (bound at Main.hs:59:11)
        nodeSet :: MapGraph e n -> S.Set n1 (bound at Main.hs:59:3)
   |
59 |   nodeSet mapGraph = S.fromList $ M.keys $ mGraph mapGraph
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I have no idea what the error message is trying to tell me except that I have something wrong with type signatures. The type of `tetsNodeSet` looks correct to me

```
testNodeSet :: Ord a => MapGraph e a -> S.Set a
```

What do I need to do to fix my issue? I did wonder if I need to add `(Ord e,Ord n) =>` to my declaration of the data type `MapGraph` but I couldn't work out how to put it there without getting a compile error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class is making a very strong promise, which is hard to keep later on:

```
class Graph g where
  nodeSet :: (Ord n) => g -> S.Set n
```

This is promising that, from any `Graph` type `g`, we can build a set of `n`, for *any* ordered type `n`.

That is, if we have `instance Graph G where ...` then from `G` we must be able to construct a `nodeSet` of type `S.Set Bool`, another of type `S.Set String`, and so on for `S.Set Int`, `S.Set [Bool]`, etc.

Likely, this is not what you want. You don't want to promise "from a graph you can get a set of any type", but something like "from a graph you can get a set of nodes of a fixed type which depends on the graph type".

This dependency can be expressed in Haskell in many ways, e.g. using type families

```
class Graph g where
    type Node g
    nodeSet :: g -> S.Set (Node g)   -- no need for Ord right now
```

Here we declare a type family `Node g` which depends on `g`. Then we can write

```
instance (Ord e,Ord n) => Graph (MapGraph e n) where
   type Node (MapGraph e n) = n
   nodeSet mapGraph = S.fromList $ M.keys $ mGraph mapGraph
```

to define the type of nodes specific to the instance at hand.

You will need to enable a bunch of Haskell extensions to make this work, but hopefully the idea is clear.

---

Here's how to read the compiler's error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘n1’ with ‘n’
```

A type `n1` should have been equal to `n`, but it was not. Here's where these two type come from:

```
  ‘n1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      nodeSet :: forall n1. Ord n1 => MapGraph e n -> S.Set n1
```

`n1` is the type which is mentioned in the class (the one called `n` in your code)

```
  ‘n’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the instance declaration
```

`n` is the type mentioned din the instance (which bares no relation to `n1`).

```
  Expected type: S.Set n1
    Actual type: S.Set n
```

The class promised `S.Set n1`, but your code returned a `S.Set n`. To make these two types equal, we would need `n1` and `n` equal, but there is no guarantee that they are such.

Comment: What a great answer, it explained why it was wrong as well as helping my with the answer I needed. For this to work I needed to add `{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}` at the top of my file, which I assume is correct due to you mentioning type families in your answer. I have not come across type families so I will have to research more into that